# Compare only Date between two columns of datatime objects in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following subset of my data, the actual dataset is much larger. I would like to select only the rows where the year month and day are equal between Quote_Time and Last_Trade_Date, regardless of the time being different. Wondering what the best way to do that would be.

```
                  Quote_Time           Last_Trade_Date
72  2018-06-14T13:41:28.000Z  2018-06-08T19:58:04.000Z
75  2018-06-14T13:56:23.000Z  2018-06-08T19:58:04.000Z
78  2018-06-14T14:11:15.000Z  2018-06-08T19:58:04.000Z
81  2018-06-14T14:26:09.000Z  2018-06-08T19:58:04.000Z
84  2018-06-14T14:41:14.000Z  2018-06-08T19:58:04.000Z
```

In this small example no rows would be returned, but in the larger dataset there are matches.

Comment: So the result here is no rows are selected?

Comment: Ty `df[df['Quote_Time'].dt.date==df['last_Trade_Date'].dt.date]`

Comment: I guess they're not datetime objects at the moment, theyre just objects. Quote_Time object, Last_Trade_Date object

Comment: If you have already read in the data without parsing as dates, try `df[pd.to_datetime(df['Quote_Time']).dt.date==pd.to_datetime(df['last_Trade_Date']).dt.date]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a prereq, when reading in your data, parse the date columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', ..., parse_dates=['Quote_Time', 'Last_Trade_Date'])
```

Now you just need to normalize the dates and compare. Assuming both columns are datetimes, you can do:

```
df[df['Quote_Time'].dt.normalize() == df['Last_Trade_Date'].dt.normalize()]
```

Or,

```
df[df['Quote_Time'].dt.date == df['Last_Trade_Date'].dt.date]
```

---

Another fun solution using `nunique` (not as practical):

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.normalize(), axis=1).nunique(axis=1) == 1]
```